# Is it possible to save the workspace settings of a CI in a repository?

Tags: jenkins, repository, continuous-integration, branch

We have a long life cycle for our software releases. That we need a continuous integration server also for our branches.

The problem is that we have the sources of the software in a repository but not the jobs of the Jenkins server. One problem is that the jobs for a branch use other repository URLs. But also many other settings of the jobs can change over the years.

Ideally the configuration of the CI server would be also branched.

- Is it possible to start any CI server with a configuration in a repository?
- Is it possible to use placeholders in the repository URL that will be replaced with the branch of the CI configuration?

Answer (score 1):

See the [SCM Sync configuration plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SCM+Sync+configuration+plugin):

> *SCM Sync Configuration Jenkins/Hudson plugin is aimed at 2 main features:*
>
> - *Keep sync'ed your config.xml (and other ressources) jenkins/hudson files with a SCM repository*
> - *Track changes (and author) made on every file with commit messages*